# How do I make a fixed div of text change as content changes?

Tags: jquery, html, fixed, scrolltop

I have a page where my content, which are images, scrolls down and has a fixed title on the side. I require the title on the side which is a fixed div, to change as the images roll up, to describe each image.

Please see http://kimcolemanprojects.com/artworks.html

thanks for any advice on how to achieve this.

angela

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add a small (as possible) example that demonstrates the problem? That way it's easier for us to help you, and when you fix the problem on your site (or the link changes) this question will still be useful to future visitors. In addition it would help to know what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written some weeks ago a simple jQuery expression, so here's a simple solution that fits to your requirements...

**jQuery expression**

```
jQuery.expr.filters.inView = function(el) {
    var width = $(el).width(),
        height = $(el).height(),
        offset = $(el).offset(),

        vp_dimensions = {
            height: $(window).height(),
            width: $(window).width()
        },
        y_offset = (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop),
        x_offset = (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);

    return (
    offset.top < (y_offset + vp_dimensions.height) && offset.left < (x_offset + vp_dimensions.width) && (offset.top + height) > y_offset && (offset.left + width) > x_offset);
};
```

**Scroll Event**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    $('li').each(function() {
        var self = $(this),
            title = self.prev('.title').text();
        if (self.is(':inView')) {
            $('#title').find('h2').text(title);
        }
    });

}).scroll();
```

**[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ejxMJ/)**

**Update**

To do it a bit nicer I've removed your placeholder `.title`'s and added its contents to your img-alt attributes:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    $('li').each(function() {
        var self = $(this),
            title = self.find('img').attr('alt');
        if (self.is(':inView')) {
            $('#title').find('h2').text(title);
        }
    });

}).scroll();
```

And your new HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="title">
        <h2>Untitled 1</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main" class="main">
    <ul>
        <li id="1">
            <a onClick="goToByScroll('2')" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="Untitled17.jpg" alt="Unititled 1"></a>
        </li>
        <li id="2">
            <a onClick="goToByScroll('3')" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="Untitled9.jpg" alt="Unititled 2"></a>
        </li>
        <li id="3">
            <a onClick="goToByScroll('4')" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="Frame2.jpg" alt="Unititled 3"></a>
        </li>
        <li id="4">
            <a onClick="goToByScroll('1')" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="Untitled2.jpg" alt="Unititled 4"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/EhUD6/)**

## UPDATE

I've rebuild your link anchors and removed the "inline-onclick"-events:

[Complete Site](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9fdqs/show) - [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9fdqs)

Comment: Just trying it out now, however it seems to stop my click scroll script from working? Is that because of the jquery version?

Comment: To that I've to say, that an `ID` or `class` can not start with an number... give them an id like this: `<li id="u1">`, `<li id="u2">` etc.

Comment: ok, thanks for advice, however I still need my images to scroll to top when clicked as well as the titles changing. Is this possible? thanks for you time

Comment: @user1566289 Can you explain that a bit further?

Comment: function goToByScroll(id){
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
}      when you click on an image it should scroll up to next image on page, so its one long page of images that you can view by clicking each image to see the next image scroll up into view. which the above code was doing.

Comment: @user1566289 I've done that already in my last update: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9fdqs/show If it is as you've expected, mark this question as answered and vote my answer up :)

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is watch the scroll event with jQuery and check the scroll position as you go.

Here is a generic example:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
  to_top = $(document).scrollTop();
  if ( $('img').offset().top == to_top ) {
      $('#id-of-title-div').text('text to change to');
  }
});
```

Comment: I have used that code and done this but it doesn't work properly, what  am I doing wrong.    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
  to_top = $(document).scrollTop();
  if ( $('#1').offset().top = to_top ) {
      $('#title').text('photogram1');
  }
});   $(window).scroll(function(){ 
  to_top = $(document).scrollTop();
  if ( $('#2').offset().top = to_top ) {
      $('#title').text('photogram2');
  }
});  ect ??

Comment: First of you do everything in the `$(window).scroll` event. You dont want multiple of those. You will just have multiple if statements or if else statements. You can also us a switch statement